# How to properly remove a column from AspNetUsers table that was created during a migration with Package Manager Console?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I added a new table to the identity's database, and I think I messed up because now in the AspNetUsers table I have a new column thats a foreign key to my new table and I don't want that in there. 
What is the best way to remove that new column?

This is how I started off

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        ...
        public virtual SuperAdminHistory SuperAdminHistory { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my class

```
public class SuperAdminHistory
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SuperAdminHistoryID { get; set; }

        public string SuperAdminIdCreator { get; set; }

        public string CreatedAdminID { get; set; }

        public string DateCreated { get; set; }

        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public string ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

and then I added this to the ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SuperAdminHistory> SuperAdminHistory { get; set; }
```

I then when into the Package Manager Console
and did

> Add-Migration "NewTable"

Then...

> Update-Database

At first I made a couple mistakes when trying to create a new table, so I am wondering if the earlier mistakes created the foreign key in my AspNetUsers table.

The AspNetUsers table now looks like this
[image: AspNetUsers Table]

and my new table is now in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a navigation property, it creates a relationship and EF will add a foreign key. If you don't want that, do:

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual SuperAdminHistory SuperAdminHistory { get; set; }
```

or add the fluent mapping: .Ignore(p => p.SuperAdminHistory);

If you make that change and apply a migration it should remove the field. Another option is to rollback your prior migration:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"name_of_migration"
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way is write proper SQL script and apply on database.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_AspNetUsers_YOURKEYNAME]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AspNetUsers]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUsers_YOURKEYNAME]
GO

alter table AspNetUsers
    drop coulmn SuperAdminHistory_SuperAdminHistoryID
```

Comment: The next time he runs a migration it's going to add it right back if you don't fix the model.